# Revit API events with pyRevit

Tags: python, ironpython, revit-api, pyrevit

I'm trying to use the revit api events on my iron python addins (using pyRevit to add the ribbon and pushbuttons) but I don't really understand what to do.

I found this piece of code but I couldn't make it work. For starters, I'd like to print "View activated" each time a view is activated

https://github.com/eirannejad/pyRevit/issues/201

```
from System import EventHandler, Uri
from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Events import ViewActivatedEventArgs, ViewActivatingEventArgs

def event_handler_function(sender, args):
   # do the even stuff here

# I'm using ViewActivating event here as example.
# The handler function will be executed every time a Revit view is activated:
__revit__.ViewActivating += EventHandler[ViewActivatingEventArgs](event_handler_function)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you checked the latest [documentation](https://www.notion.so/Create-Your-First-Hook-0214eee855fc43cead1e6f30f586a04e)?

According to the wiki, you just need to create a .py/.cs file under a folder named hook and name the file as the [event](https://www.notion.so/Extension-Hooks-b771ecf65f6a45fe87ae12beab2a73a6) you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can look a the Revit SDK sample **Events/EventsMonitor**. It shows you how to subscribe to many Revit events in C#, including `ViewActivating`. The subscription mechanism and functionality is identical in all .NET languages.